# Como colocar uma imagem na frente de um botão?

Tags: css

Estou tentando, sem sucesso colocar uma imagem (ícone do Facebook) a frente de um formulário de *newsletter*:

[image]

Tentei ajustar o tamanho, mas não obtive sucesso pelo meu pouco conhecimento em CSS, tentei diminuir o campo do `form` e até mesmo a posição do botão.

Esse é o html do `form`:

```
<div id="newsletter-wrap">
    <form action="newsletter.php"  method="post" class="content-form clearfix" id="newsletter-form">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar" />
        <input id="newsletter" type="email" name="newsletter" placeholder="Fique por dentro de nossas ofertas">
     </form>
     <img src="imagens/icone-facebook.png" width="29" height="29">
     <p class="status"></p>             
     <br>
</div>
```

Tenho esse CSS do `form`:

```
#newsletter-wrap {
    padding-top: 1px;
    /*border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;*/
}

#newsletter-form input#newsletter {
    float: left;
    width: 360px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#newsletter-form input.button {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#newsletter-wrap .tip {
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

O formulário da *newsletter* está dentro de uma `div`:

```
<div class="one-half column-last">O formulário está aqui</div>

.one-half {
   width: 80%;
   max-width: 460px;
}

.column-last { 
   margin-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: na frente? substituir?

Comment: Preciso só colocar a imagem do facebook na frente do botão "enviar" do formulário @Matheus Cristian

Comment: ver se a resposta abaixo te atende....

Comment: Olá @Matheus Cristian, a imagem agora ficou a direita mas ainda abaixo do form, obrigado por ter respondido.

Comment: de qual tamanho esta o form? se possível tente aumenta-la

Comment: Essas respostas dizendo para "colocar dentro do `form`"... Não concordo que é a melhor forma por questões óbvias: **A imagem não faz parte do formulário**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edite a estrutura. Se o botão vem *depois* do `input` não existe motivo pra colocar ele *antes* no HTML.

```
<form action="newsletter.php" method="post" class="content-form clearfix" id="newsletter-form">
  <input id="newsletter" type="email" name="newsletter" placeholder="Fique por dentro de nossas ofertas">
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar">
  <img src="imagens/icone-facebook.png" width="29" height="29">
</form>
```

Para ajustar seu layuot e abrir espaço para que o `img` fique à direita:

```
.one-half {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

O `input` e o botão são alinhados com `float: left` e o `img` com `float: right`.

```
#newsletter-form input#newsletter {
   float: left;
   width: 360px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   display: inline;
}

#newsletter-form input.button {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

#newsletter-wrap img {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira aproximar mais o ícone do facebook do botão Enviar, é só adicionar um `margin-right` no `img` e ir ajustando até chegar onde você quer.

Comment: Excepcional dica @André Ribeiro, agradeço a grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

A imagem esta por fora da `form` e como `form` é um `block` então a imagem tem que esta dentro da `tag` `form`, tente colocar a `tag` `img` dentro do `form` e acrescente a sua css:

```
#newsletter-wrap img{
    display:block;
    float:right;
}
```